# How to create 2 maven projects with single POM file

Tags: java, maven

For example I have a project **X** and I have to create JMH project **Y** but as there is no need of any other extra dependecies, I don't want to create another POM for project **Y** instead I can make use of project **X** POM file.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want to use like this?

Comment: Why is this tagged jmh? Would those two projects be entirely independent or in some way related to each other? Same vcs repository or different ones?

Comment: A pom does not only contain dependencies. It also contains a groupId, artifactId, possibly a parent, plugins with their configuration, build settings... Maybe the pom would be 99% identical right now, but it is absolutely not going to be 100% identical because at least the artifactId is going to differ. And at some point the version is going to differ too.

Answer (score 1):

Every project needs a POM file.

If you have common configuration, you can create a parent POM and use it in both projects.

Answer (score 1):

There's several alternatives. More straight forward are:

- create a parent pom with dependencies and inherit that OR
- create a [dependency pom](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) and import that OR
- create a [BOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms) (bill-of-materials) and import that

into both of your projects. That takes care of the dependencies, but you need to have separate pom xmls for other stuff that is in there - at least artifact id and its version. They don't need to contain much but they need to be present for maven build to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a single IntelliJ Idea project, create a pom.xml, and create 2 dirs that will be your projects.

For example:

- .idea
- projectXDir
- prokectYDir
- pom.xml
- other files